# Subsets of a monoid closed under left-multiplication by elements of a submonoid

Tags: reference-request, terminology, computer-science, semigroups, monoid

Let $M, T$ be monoids (or, semigroups) with $M \subset T$.
Then we can consider subsets $S$ of $T$ that are closed under left-multiplication by something in $M$, i.e.
$$
a \in S, m \in M \implies ma \in S \tag{$*$}
$$
Have these subsets been studied?  What can we say about the structure of them?
References would be appreciated.

---

**Motivation:** this setup seems to be a natural abstraction for the idea of [complexity classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class).  As a simple example, let $M$ be the set of Turing-computable functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and let $T$ be the set of *all* functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, with multiplication given by $fg := g \circ f$.  Let $L_1, L_2$ be languages in $T$, by which I mean functions $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$.  Then a [mapping reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction) from $L_1$ to $L_2$ is simply a function $f$ such that $fL_2 = L_1$.
The set of Turing-recognizable (recursively enumerable) languages naturally satisfies $(*)$, as does the set of co-Turing-recognizable languages.

Similarly, if $T$ is before and $M$ is the set of polynomial time computable functions, then a complexity class could be defined as a set of languages satisfying $(*)$.  In particular, standard examples like NP, coNP, NP$\cap$coNP, ExpTime, and PSpace are just examples of subsets of $T$ satisfying $(*)$, and we might naturally be interested in considering all such subsets, or at least in considering the structure of such subsets.

Other concepts can be formalized nicely.  For example, a language $l$ is NP-complete if and only if NP is "generated" by $l$, i.e. $\text{NP} = \text{P}l$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply call them **left-$M$-invariant subsets of $T$**? Such terminology fits similar things throughout algebra.

---

By definition $\color{red}{\text{some}}\,$ are just (either the empty set or the) left ideals of $M$ *anyway* since $M\subset T$. Quoting Howie's [*"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamentals-Semigroup-Mathematical-Society-Monographs/dp/0198511949) (with different notation):

> **Definition:** A non-empty subset $S$ of a semigroup $M$ is called a *left ideal* if $MS\subseteq S$.

But the condition  $$(\forall a\in S\,\forall m\in M)\quad ma\in S$$ is equivalent to $MS\subseteq S$. We can thus say a lot about the structure of $\color{red}{\text{these}}$ "left-$M$-invariant subsets".

---

They're *semigroup actions* of $M$ on $T$ (or "$M$-sets in $T$", etc.). They're not all such actions but that's what your sets are. See the *Actions* section of **Chapter 1** in Cain's [*"Nine Chapters on the Semigroup Art"*](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~alanc/teaching/m431/c_semigroups_ebook.pdf), particularly **Example 1.32(b)**.

To highlight an important bit:

> There is a [ . . . ] notion of a *left semigroup action* of $M$ on $S$ [$\subseteq T$], which is an operation $\cdot:M\times S\to S$ satisfying $$m\cdot(n\cdot s)=(mn)\cdot s.$$

We're in some semigroup $T$ though so left-multiplication fits the bill.

(Left) semigroup actions have been studied extensively.

Comment: Well, the thing is they are more like modules over a ring than the special case of ideals over a ring.  The set $S$ is not a subset of $M$, but rather a subset of $T$.  So it is closed under multiplication by things in $M$, but it is a bigger set.

Comment: *"[I]t is closed under multiplication by things in M, but it is a bigger set."* I tried to acknowledge that. I'm sorry if it's not clear. The subsets of $T$ (under your conditions) that happen to be subsets of $M$ *are* semigroup-theoretic left ideals of M. The rest are invariant under left-multiplication by $M$, so are "left-$M$-invariant subsets of $T$".

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks, yeah.  They definitely behave a lot like ideals, and not just for the ones restricted to $M$.

Comment: I'm going to talk to a semigroup theorist later today in fact. I'll mention this if we have time :)

Comment: @Goos Is that helpful? :)

Comment: Ah!  Very helpful.  Thanks a ton!  I will wait for any other answers to come around, then accept this some time later.

Comment: That seems reasonable :)